# CPU spikes up to more than 1000% of java when building in android studio. Mac shuts down while this happens

Tags: macos, java, android, macbook-pro, macos-catalina

It's been 2 weeks now and I have been trying to find the root cause of this.

Configuration: 16GB - 256GB - 15 inch Macbook Pro 2019, 2.4 GHz with 8-Core Intel Core i9 - macOS Catalina - Android Studio 4.1

What happens:

- Android Studio IDE works all good and normal while I code.
- As soon as I build a project, there comes a time when CPU usage for a java process spikes to more than 1000% (screenshot attached) and sometimes upto 1500%.
- Mac starts overheating. Strange thing is, if the mac is in charging mode, it doesn't shuts down while if it's not, it shuts down.
- The Mac shutdowns for around 1 minute and then is turned on again and continue doing the task was doing previously. (This is what make me confused since I am not quite sure if it was a shutdown actually, everythin points out to that because fans are paused, screen is turned off, touch bar & keyboard lights are turned off, the mac remains exactly as if it were shutdown but it is turned on suddenly after 1 minute to continue doing what it was doing before this happened, which is so weird)
- Mac performs very normal on any other work be it browsing or video calls or streaming.

What all I have tried:

- Tried building a basic Hello World project (CPU for java still spikes till 800%)
- Tried experimenting with increase in heap sizes.
- Reinstalled android studio.
- Ran Mac hardware diagnostics. - No issues found.
- Made a reset on SMC and NVRAM.
- Factory reset Mac and reinstalled macOs Catalina

Currently my laptop has only two third party softwares - Chrome and Android Studio.

I found a lot of questions on CPU spikes till 300 percent and their solutions were all directed towards checking for third party apps and hardware issues or optimising android studio. None of them worked for me. Please help me out with this as it's affecting my work and efficiency.

[image]

Comment: The Android build process and gradle make use of parallel instances, hence a CPU utilization of 800% is not unexpected. However that a software can cause your system to crash by just utilizing multiple CPU cores indicates that your hardware may have a defect.

Comment: Updating the question to specify that the laptop is a MacbookPro from 2019 and it is an 2.4 GHz with 8-Core Intel Core i9.

Comment: 8 cores × 2 threads (hyper-threading) means up to 1600% CPU utilization.

Answer (score 1):

The 1000% figure, btw, is because in the top part of Activity Monitor, 100% is 'one core'. 1000% therefore would imply 10 cores are fully utilised [or the data reading has hiccupped because it got too busy to keep count.]
The figures at the bottom are for the entire CPU, which definitely shows it's fully 98% busy.

Compiling always uses as many threads & cores as it can. That in itself is not the issue. The issue is your Mac can't keep itself cool enough on battery power whilst maintaining 98% busy; either the battery is weak, or there's insufficient airflow. Whether you are actually suffering an overheat shutdown or a power-starve shutdown is hard to tell from just that data.

One way I've used in the past for compiling with fewer cores is to run a VM of the same OS in Parallels [or Fusion etc] & assign it only the number of 'real' cores your Mac has. That way it only uses 'half power' at compile.

This, apart from reducing the overall load, means you have cores left outside the VM so you can keep on working on something else without being bogged down by the compile taking 97% of your CPU power. You could reduce that still further by assigning the VM even fewer cores.

Your only real alternative is to keep it plugged into the mains, or investigate the battery & airflow.

<sup>Since writing this, I just discovered VMWare are offering a free version of Fusion Player which might be useful to test this out. I've not followed the link right through the signup, just looked at the first page, & I don't use VMWare myself, I use Parallels, but it might be worth a shot - https://my.vmware.com/web/vmware/evalcenter?p=fusion-player-personal</sup>

Comment: +1. It's either a faulty unit or faulty design. @OP, you could try replacing the laptop. If a new one has the same problem, then it's the latter and if you don't want to resort to the VM hack, stepping down to a less powerful CPU is the only permanent solution (other than not buying Macs).

Comment: @gronostaj - we have no clue how old the Mac or battery is. They should be absolutely capable of running at full-tilt all day; that's perfectly within design spec. Mine can [& does], even if it means the fans are ramped up to takeoff speed. I only use the VM because I prefer to be able to hear myself think at the same time ;)

Comment: Hi @Tetsujin, regarding how old the mac & battery are, they are from 2019, my macbook has exactly 11 months since I bought it completely new.

Comment: OK, then test if it still crashes with 90% charge or more, & sitting on a table in a cool room, not on your lap & not in a heatwave. It might be useful to have something like iStat menus installed so you can check temperatures. ...& wait until spotlight & iCloud sync have finished [mdworker & bird]

Comment: @Tetsujin Gotcha, so, I tested it out in my room with 90% and MacBook did not turn off. I think is worthy to mention that this 'shutdowns' are temporary, like for around 1 minute and then is automatically turned on and continue doing the task until is finished (it can take many shutdowns). This only happened to me when the battery was lower than 20% and not plugged. (A couple of times when it was 45% but really weird and specific cases). I went to a Mac Center (where they have air condition and tables are so cool) and could not reproduce the issue even with 15% of battery.

Comment: hmm.. then I'm a bit stuck - I can't think of what would cause something that appears to be a shutdown, but isn't. If it had actually restarted the compile would have failed, so maybe it's shutting off the graphics to try continue. It's something I've never heard of or experienced, so I'm out of ideas.

Comment: I see. I added that specific part to the question, but what you mention regarding cooling makes sense, that would explain why it did not happen when I was in the Apple support center. Weird that my old 2017 macbook works in my home without issues and the battery actually says need to be replaced, but even with that it allows me to use the CPU at Max until the battery is with 0%.